# Linear Algebra proof involving traces and rank one projections

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, trace

How does one prove that if $T$ is a non-negative linear operator over a finitely generated Hilbert space that satisfies $tr(T^2)=tr(T)=1$, then $T$ must be a rank one projection? I am sorry to give no more details or any work at all. I don't even know where to start! My issue comes from a claim done in the following lecture http://pirsa.org/displayFlash.php?id=12090000

Comment: **Hint** What can you say about the eigenvalues of $T$?

Comment: What do you mean with 'finitely generated Hilbert space'? That it's dimension is finite?

Comment: They must be non-negative. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ and $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda$ then $0\leq \langle v,Tv\rangle=\langle v,\lambda v\rangle=\lambda\langle v,v\rangle=\lambda\|v\|^2\rightarrow\lambda\geq 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I mean that is dimension is finite

Comment: The video you linked is pretty long. Is there a particular part you'd like us to have a look at? It's entirely possible that the case for a finite-dimensional Hilbert space is generally instructive, but not enough for the application you'd like to use this result for. Please consider accepting the answer if it did answer your question. If not - is there something missing?

Answer (score 1):

We're considering a non-negative operator $T$ in a finite-dimensional Hilbert space (let's call the dimension $n$).

The operator $T$ is non-negative, so it is hermitian and all of its eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \dots \lambda_n$ are $\geq 0$ (eigenvalues counted with multiplicities, i.e. they need not to be distinct).

Since the trace of $T$ equal to the sum of the eigenvalues, we have ${\rm tr} T=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = 1.$ Since all of the summands are nonnegative, we have $\lambda_i \in [0,1]$ for all $i=1,\dots ,n$

The eigenvalues of $T^2$ are $\lambda_1^2 , \dots \lambda_n^2$, so we have ${\rm tr T^2}=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 = 1.$

For $a\in (0,1),$ we have $a^2 < a,$ but the sum above isn't getting any smaller ($\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2$) . So we have that every eigenvalue needs to be either equal to $0$ or $1$, but since ${\rm tr} T = 1,$ only one eigenvalue can be equal to $1$ and the other need to be equal to $0$.

That is, $T$ is the identity on the span of the one-dimensional eigenspace to the eigenvalue $1$ and zero on its orthogonal complement, i.e. a projection with rank $1$.

Comment: Thanks! This is a great answer but I just have one question. How can one assure that the characteristic polynomial of $T$ splits? In other words, how can we be certain that $T$ has eigenvalues?

Comment: @IvánMauricioBurbano: By definition, $T$ is nonnegative if $\langle x,Tx\rangle \geq 0.$ In particular, this needs to be real, i.e. $T$ is necessarily hermitian. A hermetian matrix is always diagonalizable (or in other words, its characteristic polynomial always splits).